# ruby how to create gemfile / gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, file, heroku

I am hobbyist coder. I created a twitch chat bot and now am trying deploy it Heroku. I wrote this code with ruby without rails and I don't have any gemfile or etc. its works fine on my machine but I don't know how to create for Heroku 
I tried like that and I had this error:

```
Enumerating objects: 18, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 4.87 KiB | 997.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to stormy-refuge-29575.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/stormy-refuge-29575.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/stormy-refuge-29575.git'
```

github link:https://github.com/sydneyfunnelAIO/twitch-bot

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to deploy? If you wrote it purely in Ruby, is it actually a web application at all?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts believe it or not you can write web apps in pure Ruby

Comment: its not web application. its taking datas from twitch irc and giving irc datas. its simple. i will add github link

Comment: Heroku requires a Gemfile to recognize that it's a ruby app per [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#declare-app-dependencies). You need to look at the answer by @jan.zikan. Per heroku "Heroku recognizes an app as a Ruby app by the existence of a Gemfile file in the root directory"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the gems that you are using in your application should be present in the `Gemfile`. The reason why the app is running on your computer might be that you have those gem installed globally.

Because you are using `rufus-scheduler`, `selenium-webdriver` gems, both should be present in the `Gemfile`, that should look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rufus-scheduler'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Once your `Gemfile` exists, run command `bundle install` that will install the gems and create `Gemfile.lock` file.

Answer (score 7):

If it's in ruby you just need to do

```
bundle install
```